# Is it possible to capture all 'Not Sent' reasons from email sends on an hourly basis using REST API?

Tags: rest-api, email, automation

I would like to find an automated solution that runs on an hourly basis that captures all responses from email sends from the account, including all not sent records, this will need to be captured into a data extension and then extracted into SFTP.

Originally I have attempted to use the Send Log data extension to join error codes with the data views and an error code DE to capture all not sent reasons. However, not all Not Sent reasons are captured in the Send Log.

I would like to try using the REST API to capture this data instead, but want to check if anyone else has found a solution for this and can point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.